# 'object.Activate' not working properly in Excel 2013

Tags: excel, vba

I have a custom ribbon with two drop-downs listing the open workbooks and worksheets in the active workbook.  Click on a workbook, and the ribbon does wb.Activate, click on a worksheet, and it does ws.Activate.  Simple.  My worksheets all have two panes.  A top pane with column headers and a lower pane with rows of data.  When you select a workbook via the custom-ribbon, the selected workbook appears and seems to have the focus.  However, if you use the mouse-wheel to scroll vertically through the rows of data, the lower pane instantly expands.  The top of the pane moves up, the left moves left or right.  The bottom right corner stays where it is.  The pane overwrites whatever was there on the screen.

Annoying and ugly, but what also happens is much worse.  The window APPEARS to have the focus.  However, click a button on the ribbon above the active sheet, whatever command you selected gets applied to the workbook that previously was active!  Not fun.  Often, after selecting a workbook, and scrolling with the mouse wheel, one click will either make a disaster of the screen, as Excel 2013 paints cells all over the place, or Excel will instantly disappear from your screen ... without warning or error.  It's just gone.

This only effects Excel 2013.  The same ribbon works great with Excel 2010.  It also effects all machines.  I have a half dozen machines .. VM's ... dual xeon servers ... laptops  ... workstations.  All have the same problem.  And... it's only with my account.  Log in with another Windows account, and the problem doesn't appear.

What could be causing this, and how do I get rid of it?

Comment: can you add some code to help you .

Comment: This is one of the bits that causes problems...

Comment: This is one of the bits of code that causes the problem to appear.  The click event of the dropdown on the Ribbon...

    Public Sub r_Workbooks_Select(control As IRibbonControl, id As String, index As Integer)
    
       Dim wbook As Workbook, wbname$
    
       If index >= 0 And index < last_wb_count Then
          wbname = last_wb_list(index)
          For Each wbook In Workbooks
             If wbook.Name = wbname Then
                wbook.Activate
                Exit Sub
             End If
          Next
       End If
    
    End Sub

Comment: After the selected wbook moves to the front, move the mouse cursor in to the lower pane of the active window, and roll the mouse-wheel up or down one click.  The screen is mess.  Press the "save" icon in the top-left corner.  The workbook that previously had the focus will get saved.

Actually, I found that anywhere in the code where I do a wbook.Activate or ws.Activate, the problem occurs.  Excel 2013 makes a mess of things.  This code has been working for more than 10 years, with every version of Excel ever released ... except for 2013.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is likely to be fixed if you disable screen updating before changing sheet / workbook, and reset it when you are done.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193498.aspx

I also suggest you make your code more robust than the lousy example from microsoft, and make sure you reset screenupdating even if an error occurs. Leaving screenupdating to false means you will basically have to restart excel.

Comment: Sounded promising, so I tried adding the following to the Ribbon Code ...

   on error resume next

   hupd = Application.ScreenUpdating
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False

   xxx.Activate

   For t=1 to 10: DoEvents: Next t
   Application.ScreenUpdating = hupd

   on error goto 0

... no luck, unfortunately.   Select the dropdown , move the mouse to the window that appears, roll back the mouse wheel one click and ... voila ... a mess.  Click on a button on the ribbon above the window.  The button effects the windows that previously had the focus.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: This is insane ... what did Microsoft do to Excel 2010 when they went from MDI to SDI in Excel 2013 ?

Comment: My gut feeling is that it has something to do with the strange things Excel 2013 is doing with the Window Border.  You see it constantly converting itself from a Windows 7 Aero border to a flat Windows 8 border.  My guess is that something is happening to the Window that is making the GDI routines think that the window's titlebar has a height of zero.  Everything is being rendered higher than it should.   What is causing the ribbon buttons to effect the wrong workbook, is any body's guess.  I have no idea what is going on here.

Comment: The screen updating is broken since 2013, so even if you disable it, you will still see the windows flicker...

As for your problem, maybe it's related to the recent patch MS released that broke activation in some cases : http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/search/search?SearchTerm=KB3085502&IsSuggestedTerm=false&tab=&CurrentScope.ForumName=Office&CurrentScope.Filter=office_2013_release&ContentTypeScope=QnA%2CDiscussion%2CWiki#/Office//QnA,Discussion,Wiki/1

But from your question, I suppose you don't call rng.Hasformula, hasArray or NumberFormat, so you shouldn't be impacted...

Comment: The Office Forum article you mentioned matches my problem exactly.  I also found this one that even has screenshots showing the exact same problem:  [link](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2013_release-excel/excel-2013-32-bit-kb3085502-vba-bugissue/f7b6f2e4-c24c-41f4-a4fd-2335cba85287/).
The articles say the solution is to uninstall KB3085502 and KB3085583.  I can find nothing in these patches that could cause something like this, so I don't think I can convince our IT to remove this KB from a few thousand machines.

Comment: patch KB3085502 has : 'Some object model calls (Range::HasArray, Range:HasFormula and Range::NumberFormat) are slower in Excel 2013 compared to earlier versions of Excel.' (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3085502)

They introduced a bug when they tried to make these methods faster (we build a pluggin for office in my company and we confirmed it on every machines we tested)

Are you calling one of these methods ? Or could you try your code on a machine with an older version of Office ?

It seems that the Office team is looking into it and people are expecting a fix in nov or december

Comment: My problem is only effecting Excel 2013.  It occurs on all machines running Excel 2013.  wbook.Activate brings the window to the front, but all buttons effect which ever workbook was active when the wbook.Activate was invoked. And, the screen is completely messed up.  I still have one machine running Excel 2010, and the code runs perfectly on that machine.  No strange things what so ever.  All the 2013 machines appear to have the patches mentioned in the articles.

Comment: Well seems that the fix will be coming pretty soon so maybe you'll be able to see. If not, another idea, since the button is in the ribbon, do you need to call Ribbon.InvalidateControl after changing workbook ? I don't know much about the ribbon and I don't think it would impact only excel 2013 though. Especially, I've no idea why it would impact only your account :/